# pwa product detail show custom attribute

Tags: magento2, pwa, pwa-studio

I want my website pwa to show custom product attributes. my product attribute is dropdown. Do you any have idea how to implement it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pwa product detail show prdouct attribute](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/371419/pwa-product-detail-show-prdouct-attribute)